# Android Broswer selecting elements from behind of the drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having issues creating a dropdown menu using html/css/jquery.
The issue is that when I tap on the submenu item, if on the body(beneath the submenu item) is a `<select>` element, instead of triggering the submeniu item it triggers the select element.

Any ideeas?
Updated with
[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rRVDg/1/)

Comment: please share the css.it may help to find out the prblm

Comment: ^^share styles and script

Comment: Simply create a jsfiddle. Your current code is not helpful enough.

Comment: Atm jsfiddle isn't working for me don't know why, I will return with jsfiddle when it will.